# how to use objects of the widgets in QT

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

In my application I'm having 2 widgets named as `widget` and `form`. But if i try to create a pointer object of widget `widget` in widget `form` header file , it is giving the error like "Form does not name a type". Refer my used code below:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"
#include "form.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Widget *w = new Widget();
   w->show();
  return a.exec();
 }
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
}
```

**widget.h**

```
 #ifndef WIDGET_H
 #define WIDGET_H

 #include "ui_widget.h"
 #include "form.h"
 class Widget : public QWidget, private Ui::Widget
 {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        Form *f ;//i try to create pointer object for Form
 };
 #endif // WIDGET_H
```

**form.cpp**

```
 #include "form.h"
 #include "widget.h"

 Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
 {
   setupUi(this);
 }
```

**form.h**

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include "ui_form.h"
#include "widget.h"
class Form : public QWidget, private Ui::Form
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
       explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really trying to derive a class from itself? Also, please post the actual error message, that would be more helpful.

Comment: This `two : public two` is maybe only a typo. The question is: here or there ;-)

Comment: What's in one.h? It's going to be hard to help you without the code... for example we may be thrown off by things like the unmatched `#endif` which may or may not be a problem in two.h.

Comment: i updated my full code above

Comment: @sivanesan thanks :-) that's exactly what helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `widget.h` includes `form.h`, which includes `widget.h`. The header guards (`#ifndef`) cause the second include to be skipped.

For declaring a pointer variable in a header a forward declaration will suffice:

**SomeClass.h**

```
 class Form; // forward declaration

 class SomeClass {
 public:
    SomeClass();
    // ...
 private:
    Form* form; // pointer to Form
 };
```

**SomeClass.cpp**

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() 
{
     form = new Form();
}
```

Comment: BTW, form.h includes widget.h which includes form.h. widget.h doesn't get included first. :)

Comment: @owacoder Both happen, depending on the unit that gets compiled. When widget.cpp is compiled, it includes form.h which includes widget.h.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a forward declaration of class `Form` in widget.h instead of `#include`ing form.h. The problem is that you include form.h, which includes widget.h, which *tries* to include form.h, but can't because of the include guard. Therefore, in widget.h, class `Form` is undefined, although it looks to the user to be defined.

Comment: Congrats, you were a few seconds faster :-)